# Gmail tracking image not tracking

Tags: php, gmail

I put my own **track image**  to track **opens** (when user clicks on email to open it).

Image: https://segmentation.eu/gmailer/david/soy-una-imagen.php

The PHP of this image is:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); // porque soy una imagen 
readfile("pipi.jpg");

//Llamar los datos de configuración
include('../super-config.php');

//Conectar a MySql
$bdnik=new mysqli($host_db, $usuario_db, $clave_usuario_db, $nombre_db);
$bdnik->set_charset("utf8");

//¿Estamos conectados?
if($bdnik->connect_errno){
printf("No fue posible conectar a la base de datos: %s\n", $bdnik->connect_error);
exit();
}

//blablabla log and stufff  
$bdnik->query("INSERT INTO GM_trackeame (planb) VALUES (1)");
?>
```

But the problem is that it is not tracking... google removes the image when sent programattically via the APP.... very strange.

Also, when I send via gmail web, it just gets a new url.

Comment: Gmail doesn't open remote images in e-mail for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @Calimero Very clever. And how do you think I may track the opens of the emails....? I see that there are other google chrome extensions which do it perfectly.

Comment: That's a user setting btw (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) but as a user I really don't want you to know I've read your e-mail unless I specifically perform an action to do so (e.g. click on a link or reply)

Comment: @Calimero they do it without you wanting it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailtrack-for-gmail-inbox/ndnaehgpjlnokgebbaldlmgkapkpjkkb?hl=es

Comment: well, too bad for me :-) Still good to know, you may want to write your own answer and accept it then.

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but your question as it is has been answered, you should edit your question if you're looking for a different answer.

Comment: @Calimero i opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179224/track-gmail-message-opens